# Define a custom CVSROOT for remote users

Tags: cvs

I am configuring a CVS server on a RedHat 6.

I want to create my cvs repository in the directory `/home/my_cvs_user_name/my_cvsroot` but I do not want my cvs users know the real path to that repository on the server.

Now, the user need to do:

```
export CVSROOT=:pserver:username1@my_server_name:/home/my_cvs_user_name/my_cvsroot
cvs login
...
```

How can I configure CVS so that they can connect to the cvs server with a url such as:

```
export CVSROOT=:pserver:username1@my_server_name:/my_cvsroot
cvs login
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use a symbolic link. eg.

```
ln -s /home/my_cvs_user_name/my_cvsroot /my_cvsroot
```

You might need to play around with permissions, but it seems unlikely given they would already have had correct access when it was in your home directory.